# File is not deleted

Tags: 18.04

I have system running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and in the server there is a file called `debug.txt` which is 24GB in size. 
I tried to delete it, but I get the following error message:

```
rm: cannot remove 'debug.txt': No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a terminal to stat/file/ls the file `debug.txt` or a file.manager? (thunar, nautilus etc).  I've had circumstances before where a GUI file.manager could see a cached directory image when in terminal it wasn't there (it'd been removed by a different user on another box; the directory was network storage and not local storage)

Comment: Before running the `rm debug.txt` command, ensure that you are in the correct directory by entering the command `ls -l debug.txt`.

Comment: Better rename it instead of removing: `mv /pathtoyourfolderwithfile/debug.txt /pathtoyourfolderwithfile/debug.txt.bk` and check if you could reboot and login as usually. Then you could try to remove it: `rm -fr /pathtoyourfolderwithfile/debug.txt`